# A strange problem occur when I train my model using pytorch

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network

I was training my face expression recognition model, but my test set accuracy is always low. So I try to find the problem.

I replace my testloader with trainloader, and I hope that I will get the same accuracy. But then the problem occur, they are different. Why? Doesn't I use the same dataset?

A result in an epoch is:

```
Loss in trainset: 1.5687

Accuracy in trainset: 18%

Accuracy of     anger :  5%
Accuracy of   disgust : 11%
Accuracy of      fear : 20%
Accuracy of     happy : 34%
Accuracy of   neutral : 25%
Accuracy of       sad : 12%
Accuracy of  surprise : 18%

-------------------------calculating accuracy-------------------------

Loss in testset: 1.6002 

Accuracy in testset: 13%

Accuracy of     anger :  0%
Accuracy of   disgust :  0%
Accuracy of      fear :  0%
Accuracy of     happy :  0%
Accuracy of   neutral : 100%
Accuracy of       sad :  0%
Accuracy of  surprise :  0%
```

My train and test code is here. Could someone help me? Thank you very much.

```py
classes = ('anger', 'disgust', 'fear', 'happy', 'neutral', 'sad', 'surprise')
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, shuffle=False, batch_size=args.bn)

model.train()

total_loss = 0.0
correct = 0.0
total = 0
sum_class = [0. for i in range(args.classnum)]
num_class = [0. for i in range(args.classnum)]

for inputs, labels in trainloader:
    # get the inputs
    inputs, labels = inputs.to(device), labels.to(device)

    # count data
    total = total + labels.shape[0]

    # wrap them in Variable
    inputs, labels = Variable(inputs), Variable(labels)

    # zero the parameter gradients
    optimizer.zero_grad()

    # forward + backward + optimize
    outputs = model(inputs)
    loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
    total_loss += loss.item()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

    results = torch.argmax(outputs, dim=1)
    correct = correct + (labels == results).sum().item()

    labels = list(labels)
    # calculate class accuracy
    for i in range(7):
        sum_class[i] = sum_class[i] + labels.count(i)
    for i in range(len(results)):
        if results[i] == labels[i]:
            num_class[results[i]] = num_class[results[i]] + 1

total_loss = total_loss / ( 1 if total == 0 else total)
total_accuracy = correct / (1 if total == 0 else total)
print('Loss in trainset: %.4f\n' % total_loss)
print('Accuracy in trainset: %d%%\n' % (total_accuracy*100))
for i in range(args.classnum):
    print('Accuracy of %9s : %2d%%' % (classes[i], 100 * num_class[i] / sum_class[i]))

print('\n-------------------------calculating accuracy-------------------------\n')


model.eval()

correct = 0
total = 0
total_loss = 0.0

sum_class = [0. for i in range(args.classnum)]
num_class = [0. for i in range(args.classnum)]

# I try to replace the testloader with trainloader, but I get the different results.
*emphasized text*
# for inputs, labels in testloader:
for inputs, labels in trainloader:
    # get the inputs
    inputs, labels = inputs.to(device), labels.to(device)

    # count data
    total = total + labels.shape[0]

    # wrap them in Variable
    inputs, labels = Variable(inputs), Variable(labels)

    outputs = model(inputs)
    loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
    total_loss += loss.item()

    results = torch.argmax(outputs, dim=1)
    correct = correct + (labels == results).sum().item()

    labels = list(labels)
    # calculate class accuracy
    for i in range(7):
        sum_class[i] = sum_class[i] + labels.count(i)
    for i in range(len(results)):
        if results[i] == labels[i]:
            num_class[results[i]] = num_class[results[i]] + 1

loss = (total_loss / (1 if total == 0 else total))
accuracy = (100 * correct / (1 if total == 0 else total))
print('Loss in testset: %.4f \n' % loss)
print('Accuracy in testset: %d%%\n' % accuracy)

for i in range(args.classnum):
    print('Accuracy of %9s : %2d%%' % (classes[i], 100 * num_class[i] / sum_class[i]))
```

Comment: you dont need to wrap input and label as Variables. Also wrap your training loop in function to reduce ambiguity. There could be two reasons behind this observations, 1) you are using dropout's or other BatchNorm or 2) the performance of your model degrades as you train it. Please share the model and analysis of your datasource (to figure out if there is any sort of class imbalance )

Comment: @Karan Dhingra
Thank you for your answer. I use ShuffleNet like this https://github.com/aWahlang/Facial-Emotion-classification-MobileNet-vs-ShuffelNet-/blob/master/shufflenet2.py  . It does have the BatchNorm layer. And my dataset is Jaffe dataset. But my test dataset accuracy is around 20%, and the train dataset accuracy could up to 90%. Do you have any suggestion? Thank you very much!!!

Comment: It implies that your model is overfitting. Ensure that the distribution of train samples is uniform and make sure that you are fine tuning properly. Also, it is very broad to answer

Comment: @Karan Dhingra OK, thank you very much!!!